# Ember.js with a third party theme template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I would like to use Ember.js with a website template from Themeforest (with html, css and js files).

A problem with the main Javascript file from the template is that it is called only one time when the document is ready, but I would like to call it each time a user change his route.

For example, each time a new route is called, there is a new `<div class="page-content"></div>`, but the following jQuery line is not executed.

```
$('.page-content').wrapInner('<div class="page-content-inner"></div>');
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue with a clean way? I don't want to change every line of the main Javascript file of the template that has about 1200 lines.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why can't you copy and paste the html into local ember templates?

Comment: Is this just one big "black box" of a JS file, or can you pick, and choose the parts you want? I'm assuming it doesn't have methods that you could invoke for the functions you want?

If it did have methods for you to use, you could get extra tricky by creating your own components for those JS/HTML pairings. But the simplest method would be to follow the example I provided in my answer.

Comment: @Moogs: the example I gave is just one little (and simple) example of Javascript. There are hundreds of class that are affected by the third party Javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [example](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/) from the Ember docs on how to add Google analytics tracking on every transition.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  notifyGoogleAnalytics: function() {
    return ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'page': this.get('url'),
        'title': this.get('url')
      });
  }.on('didTransition')
});
```

The code above would get run each time you transition between routes, and you could just define it in one place.

Comment: I used the code you suggested but I have an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.get is not a function`. Do you know why?

Comment: It would depend on what you're calling `this.get` on. Can you share an example bit of code? Like in a gist, or emberjs bin? You can pretty much only use `this.get` on an object.

Comment: Although, I believe you can use `this.get('firstObject')` on an array too. FYI.